Getting an Error "The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` has been removed." How to fix?
I am trying to use redux-toolkit to store data from an api.I tried it but I am getting this error saying "The object notation for createSlice.extraReducers has been removed. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead" Here's the code snippet:
import axios from "axios";
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createBookWithID from "../../utils/createBookWithID";
import { setError } from "./errorSlice";

const initialState = {
  books: [],
  isLoadingViaAPI: false,
};

export const fetchBook = createAsyncThunk(
  "books/fetchBook",
  async (url, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setError(error.message));
      throw error;
    }
  }
);

const bookSlice = createSlice({
  name: "books",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addBook: (state, action) => {
      state.books.push(action.payload);
    },
    deleteBook: (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        books: state.books.filter((book) => book.id !== action.payload),
      };
    },
    toggleFavorite: (state, action) => {
      state.books.forEach((book) => {
        if (book.id === action.payload) {
          book.isFavorite = !book.isFavorite;
        }
      });
    },
  },
  //OPTION 1
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchBook.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingViaAPI = true;
    },
    [fetchBook.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoadingViaAPI = false;
      if (action.payload.title && action.payload.author) {
        state.books.push(createBookWithID(action.payload, "API"));
      }
    },
    [fetchBook.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.isLoadingViaAPI = false;
    },
  },
});

I am trying to store fetched api data to jobs
